# The policy failed legacy parsing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am trying to create IAM Role in AWS, but while I am creating I am facing error

"We encountered the following errors while processing your request: 
 Problem in attaching permission to role. Role will be created without permission. 
 The policy failed legacy parsing  "

```
{"Version": "2012-10-17",  "Statement": [
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
    "logs:CreateLogStream",
    "logs:PutLogEvents"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
},
{
  "Action": [
    "sqs:SendMessage",
    "sqs:GetQueueUrl"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-northeast-1:SOME_ID_HERE:test-messages"
}]}
```

Answer (score 108):

I got this error, and couldn't figure it out.  A colleague and I pored over it, and then we spotted that I had left a substitution variable without the `Fn::Sub`, e.g.

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:logs::${AWS::AccountId}:*"
```

will cause this error, and of course should be

```
"Resource": { "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:logs::${AWS::AccountId}:*" }
```

BTW, in my experience, I agree with E.J. Brennan above, you cannot use a wildcard for region, instead leave it blank as I did there.

Comment: Unbelievable that cloudformation error reporting is so bad that you have to paper parse and debug.

Comment: I got it because I had written {AWS::Region} instead of ${AWS::Region} in a resource reference

Answer (score 26):

If it fails for s3, ensure that you are using the correct arn format:

- Correct one is 3 **:::** **arn:aws:s3:::AccountABucketName**

  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AccountABucketName"
- Wrong one 2 **::** **arn:aws:s3::AccountABucketName**

  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::AccountABucketName"

Count the number of colons between `s3` and `AccountABucketName`

Comment: wow....and I thought a missing semicolon was hard to spot....thank you!

Comment: I was coding this in CDK and had the same problem. Strings will get you every time.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using `serverless` you can indicate that you want variables substitution by prefixing the resource with `!Sub`:

```
  Resource:
    - !Sub arn:aws:dynamodb:*:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

No plugin required (if serverless version is recent).

Comment: this is the best approach; the `serverless-pseudo-parameters` plugin has even been deprecated since this came out

Answer (score 5):

A fun new error state I found today:

If:

- you have a CFN template where you provide an Account ID via a parameter
- AND you use the `Default` prop of the parameter to provide the Account ID
- AND the Account ID starts with a `0`

CFN will actually read the parameter as an integer (and cast it to like 9.3476294382E10) 
- regardless of whether you have `Type: String` on the parameter, or use `!!str` to explicitly cast it.

So the solution is to manually provide the parameter to the deployment instead of using the `Default: "093476294382"`.

Hope I can save someone else some time.

Comment: or maybe use `${AWS::AccountId}` instead

Answer (score 3):

For debugging CloudFormation syntax errors (many of which have unhelpful error messages like the one above), I suggest validating with [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) prior to deployment. You'll thank me later.

Comment: cfn-lint failed to catch my error - it's a great tool but it's not perfect!

Answer (score 1):

my issue was that i tried `"Effect": "ALLOW"` instead of `"Effect": "Allow"`. Smh...

Comment: Only the `prefix` and `action` values are case-insensitive. For example, `iam:ListAccessKeys` and `IAM:listaccesskeys` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

These tools could be useful:

### debugging tools

- UI in AWS web-console [policysim](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp) *(though, you will need permissions to use it)*
- CLI tool [accessanalyzer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/accessanalyzer/validate-policy.html) (it is not very clear how to run it without [these examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iam-access-analyzer-samples/tree/main/01-validate-policy) in GH repo)
- [CloudTrail](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/home?#/events?EventName=PutRolePolicy&CustomTime=1800000) with [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-malformed-policy-errors/#Get_more_information_on_the_AWS_CloudTrail_event_that_caused_the_error) can help you find recent issues

### also good to know

- [serverless variables](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#referencing-aws-specific-variables) (if you use `sls`), be careful with `${AWS::AccountId}` - i had `#{....}` in my config and I end up writing this
- [AWS advice on validate policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-policy-validation.html)

Have no idea why AWS CloudFormation didn't become more helpful over this time. Still any `$` or `${` will be a *great source of fun*, especially when the deployed stack is not basic (for example, you have a serverless, and every attempt takes >5 min)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can wildcard the region on the arn, so you may need something like this instead:

> `arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:*:*`

, where you specify the region you are using in place of us-east-1.

More information here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-cloudwatch-logs

Comment: Thanks for responding, though I specify the region I am getting same errors.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you may have is cloudwatch Logs ARNS can have 6 : symbols because there is an extra between log group and log stream. For example:

`"Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:123456789012:/my/log/group:log-stream"`

or for your case:

`"Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*:*`

I have found that some ARNS such as the more specific example above give this error if a 6th : is not added. I realize this does contradict the docs (including doc provided by E.J)  so perhaps it's a bug within AWS somewhere

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/iam-identity-based-access-control-cwl.html

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could do

```
    "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:123456789012:*"
```

but if not, you can map your accounts to the region with a mapping:

```
    "mAWSRegionToAccountsMap": {
        "us-west-2": {
            "prod": "444444444673",
            "dev": "678333333333"

        },
        "us-gov-west-1": {
            "dev": "12345678903",
            "prod": "234345345345"
        }
    }
```

Then integrate the mapping into a join using a ":" for the delimiter

```
    "Resource": {
        "Fn::Join": [
            ":",
            [
                "arn:aws:logs",
                { 
                    "Ref": "AWS::Region" 
                },
                {
                    "Fn::FindInMap": [
                        "mAWSRegionToAccountsMap",  {
                            "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                        },
                        "prod"
                    ]
                },
                "/*"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

May need to tweak the ending

Answer (score 0):

Had this today - `cfn-lint` was happy but I'd got:

```
- !Sub "arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:{AWS::AccountId}:network-interface/*"
```

instead of:

```
- !Sub "arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:network-interface/*"
```

A missing `$`!

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error, mine was related to a missing `$` when using `!Sub` to substitute a variable.

I.e.:

```
"Resource": { "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-northeast-1:{SOME_ID_HERE}:test-messages" }
```

When the correct expression should be:

```
"Resource": { "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-northeast-1:${SOME_ID_HERE}:test-messages" }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).